# python - how to open an Excel file and interact like human with it

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel File (.xlsm) where I have to put 2 variables in 2 cells which will modify the result in another cell. This result has to be copied and be pasted in a second Excel file.
**There are about 150 Scenarios to do in this way !**
I wanted to automatize it.

**Problem:**

- Openpyxel cannot interact with formulas
- Pycel doesn't support .xlsm files
- Lib 'formulas' would not work since the autor of the Excel File
  put name for the formulas. So instead of =SUMME(A1:A5)*MAX(D5:D8),
  there is =CALCULATIONHEIGHT (for example)

**QUESTION:** Is there any possibilities to simply do like human: tell the programm to open the file (not load, just open), put the 2 variables and extract the result ?

Thank you !

Comment: why don't you code whatever your excel file is doing without excel?

Comment: Too complicated, too much variables (very technical product) and I didn't create this excel. It has be created and coded by another department which blocked everything to avoid modifying or even seeing the content of the formulas.

Comment: Are you restricted to using python? If not, you could maybe consider your OS's version of macro's (all OS-es have them)? It's for sure human-like but comes with some downsides.

Comment: If you need to "do like human" I think you need COM-based integration with Excel: look at https://www.pyxll.com/blog/tools-for-working-with-excel-and-python/#excel-front-end